# How do i exclude the _id & __v properties when querying or creating a mongoose Document (in NestJS)?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

In my NestJS backend app i have this User Schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({
  versionKey: false,
  toJSON: { virtuals: true, getters: true },
  id: false,
})
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;
}

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

UserSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
  return this._id.toHexString();
});
```

When i query:

```
async findUserWithId(id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel.findById(id);
  }

  async findUserWithEmail(email: string): Promise<UserDocument> {
    return this.userModel.findOne({ email }).exec();
  }
```

Or create:

```
 const newUser = await new this.userModel(regsiterUserDto).save();
```

My response still includes the `_id` property. I would like this to be `id`.

```
"user": {
        "email": "dummy@email.com",
        "name": "Dummy Name",
        "_id": "64ef0ef71e64e37bb88f953d"
    },
```

How can i achieve this without manipulating the object (manually removing _id).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mongoose `select` syntax to exclude fields on queries https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.select()

For example,

```
// exclude _id, include other fields
async findUserWithId(id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel.findById(id).select('-_id');
}
```

From the documentation above,

> Specifies which document fields to include or exclude (also known as the query "projection").

> When using string syntax, prefixing a path with - will flag that path as excluded. When a path does not have the - prefix, it is included. Lastly, if a path is prefixed with +, it forces inclusion of the path, which is useful for paths excluded at the schema level.

Comment: isnt there a way to ensure all queries show id instead of manually doing -id every time? also for __v versionKey: false doesnt work for me.